# Callback can not be invoked properly, if the parameter is a bound function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux, bind

When a function expects a callback as a param, I suppose it make sense to provide a bound function like this

```
function invokeCb(cb){
    cb();
}
function test(x){
    console.log(x)
}
const para="xyz";

invokeCb(test.bind(null,para)) //(1)
invokeCb(()=>{test(para)}) //(2)
```

I can not see anything wrong with `(1)`. However, when it come to real world, I encounter some unexpected behaviour

Here is a example, in `redux`

```
store.subscribe(
    ()=>{(saveState.bind(null,store.getState()))()}
)
```

can work while

```
store.subscribe(saveState.bind(null,store.getState()))
```

can not correctly, i.e. the `store.getState()` seems never invoked properly

If you need more context. Here:https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage

Maybe I missed some subtle differences between the two form, can anyone point it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences are

- the time at which `store.getState()` is evaluated
- the return value (by using braces without `return`, you suppress it)

```
let data = "abc";
function invokeCb(cb){
    data = "xyz";
    console.log(cb());
}
function test(x){
    console.log(x);
    return x.toUpperCase();
}
invokeCb(test.bind(null, data)); // abc ABC
invokeCb(()=>{ test(data); }); // xyz undefined
```

Comment: I believe you know the answer, could you contrive a concrete example to demonstrate the difference, I really can not get your point

Comment: You are sort of correct, the problem is that `store.getState()` read the stale data

Comment: @Guigui I added an example (but didn't try it)

Comment: Thanks, things I know is that they do can have a difference, but I still can not explain about my case. This is the first time I realize it, do you know any well-understood problem caused by the similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I figured out the real cause of the bug!

Here is the code to demonstrate:

```
function invokeCb(cb){
    cb();
}
function test(x){
    console.log(x)
}

let counter=0;
function getData(){
  return ({counter:counter++})
}

const bindVersion=test.bind(null,getData())
const invokeVersion=()=>test(getData())

//first time
invokeCb(bindVersion) //{counter:0}
invokeCb(invokeVersion) //{counter:1}

//second time
invokeCb(test.bind(null,getData())) //{counter:0}
invokeCb(()=>{test(getData())}) //{counter:2}

//third time 
invokeCb(test.bind(null,getData())) //{counter:0}
invokeCb(()=>{test(getData())}) //{counter:3}
```

Explanation:

- When using the `bind` version, the parameter is **fixed**. i.e. once
  it is `bound` it can not be changed.
- One the other hand, when is    function is invoke directly, the
  parameter is **dynamic** ,i.e. it    can always get the updated data

Conclusion:

**NEVER** bind dynamic parameter to a function

In my case, case `state` is `immutable` in `redux`, `store.getState()` `return` a new reference every time, using `bind`, it always get the first reference